# How to control which attribute selector changes trigger a css animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

With the following rules:

```
.container[data-direction="reverse"] .pane[style*="display: none"]{
   animation:SlideOutToRight 1s ease;
}

.container[data-direction="forward"] .pane[style*="display: none"]{
   animation:SlideOutToLeft 1s ease;
}
```

The animation runs whenever (a) the `data-direction` attribute changes  **and** (b) whenever the style becomes `display:none`. How can I change this code so that the animation only runs when the style becomes `display:none` but **not** when the `data-direction` attribute changes?

Right now, when the direction changes, all of the containers go flying across the screen to the other side because the animation gets applied to all of them when the data attribute changes value.

The `data-direction` attribute should only control *which* animation plays, but changes to it's value should not *trigger* the animation. Is this possible?

Update:

Here is a fiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/j6ytzbh6/

Expected behavior: The forward button should cause the next sequential box to enter from the right hand side while the current box exists left. The backward button should cause the previous sequential box to enter from the left while the current box exits right. No other box should move or cross the view-port when its not it's turn to move.

Reminder: This is a CSS question, so doing the animation in javascript is cheating. The idea is that Javascript controls *functionality* (ie a box should be shown or hidden) while css controls *presentation* (ie. do we make it disappear, fade out or fly to the side). You shouldn't have to re-write your plugin to change the visual way things get shown or hidden.

Comment: Hi, we need to see a working demo with all of the relevant code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not really asking about my specific code or a code problem, I'm asking about the general ability of css to play an animation on an element selected with two selectors, when one specific selector but not the other specific selector changes state.

Comment: As soon as the states change so that it matches the selector in your CSS, the animation will fire.